# Draft refuses handshake when using java-websocket library to connect to the coinbase exchange websocket stream

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I am attempting to use the [Java-Websocket library by TooTallNate](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) to create a websocket client that receives messages from the [coinbase exchange websocket stream](https://docs.exchange.coinbase.com/). I am porting a program I made in Python to Java because of parallelisation bottlenecks in Python and to my knowledge I am doing things the same in Java as I did in Python. Here is my code to open the connection in Python using [this websocket lib](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) (This works as expected):

```
ws = websocket.create_connection("wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com", 20)
            ws.send(json.dumps({
            "type": "subscribe",
            "product_id": "BTC-USD"
        }))
```

Here is my entire Java class:

```
public class CoinbaseWebsocketClient extends WebSocketClient {

private final Gson gson = new Gson();

private CoinbaseWebsocketClient(URI serverURI) {
    super(serverURI, new Draft_17());
    connect();
}

private static URI uri;
private static CoinbaseWebsocketClient coinbaseWebsocketClient;

static {
    try {
        uri = new URI("wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected static CoinbaseWebsocketClient get() {
    if (coinbaseWebsocketClient == null) {
        coinbaseWebsocketClient = new CoinbaseWebsocketClient(uri);
    }
    return coinbaseWebsocketClient;
}

@Override
public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
    System.out.println("Websocket open");
    final JsonObject btcUSD_Request = new JsonObject();
    btcUSD_Request.addProperty("type", "subscribe");
    btcUSD_Request.addProperty("product_id", "BTC_USD");
    final String requestString = gson.toJson(btcUSD_Request);
    send(requestString);
}

@Override
public void onMessage(String s) {
    System.out.println("Message received: " + s);
}

@Override
public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    System.out.println("Websocket closed: " + reason);
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("an error occurred:" + e);
}
```

}

I know there isn't a totally fundamental issue with my Java code because it works as expected when I use ws://echo.websocket.org as the URI instead of wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com. However when I try to connect to wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com I get this error:

```
Websocket closed: draft org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_17@7ca2fefb refuses handshake
```

There is no authentication or anything like for this connection as far as I know (I didn't provide any in my Python program) so I'm at a loss as to what the source of this error is.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SocketFactory to accept all SSL certificates? That's how I (hackily) fixed my wss issue

Answer (score 1):

Need to create sslcontext like below. it skips the certificate. I was successfully able make a connection without certificate

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

// set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                    return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
            }
} }, new SecureRandom());
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you need help , post a new question

Comment: It should be a new question, not a comment. But if you want to comment wait until you have 15 rep

Comment: Add and answer hope this helps

Comment: This solved my problem, but the answer was confusing.  I submitted an edit with some formatting tweaks and an implementation note.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [`setSocket()`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java#L374) method before doing the `connect()`, e.g.:

```
private CoinbaseWebsocketClient(URI serverURI) {
    super(serverURI, new Draft_17());
    setSocket(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(serverURI.getHost(), serverURI.getPort()));
    connect();
}
```

Good luck!

---

A note: Beware that your singleton `get()` might not be a good idea in case of any failures (if I remember correctly the client class is unusable after unrecoverable error and you have to create a new client to recover).

Answer (score 0):

vlp is almost right. But should hard code **443** as port parameter:

```
private CoinbaseWebsocketClient(URI serverURI) {
    super(serverURI, new Draft_17());
    setSocket(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(serverURI.getHost(), 443));
    connect();
}
```

That works for me!

PS. the ssl must be a valid certificate one, otherwise you can not just use getDefault method to get ssl context. For self-singed, etc. please refer to following link:

http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/